# Javascript Drop button to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
$(".draggable").draggable({
    revert: true,
    helper: 'clone',
    start: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).fadeTo(0, 1);
    }
});

$("#droppable").droppable({
    hoverClass: 'active',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        this.value = $(ui.draggable).text();
    }
});
```

});

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="draggable">here are some draggables</div>
<div class="draggable">you can drop any of these</div>
<div class="draggable">in the text box and the</div>
<div class="draggable">text will be set to its contents!</div>
<div id="droppableHolder">
    Drop in this text box:<br />
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="droppable" />
</div>
```

In below link's example , If i drop any text to textbox.It works very well.

http://jsfiddle.net/5DCZw/2/

**My question:**

I want to set a button.If i drag button i want to integrated button to page.

How would code change according to my scerenaio ?

Comment: You want to convert `draggable div` to buttons?

Comment: Do you mean make buttons draggable?

Comment: yes draggable buttons